# Android Volley sending json data getting error

Tags: android, android-volley

I am try to login using volley notwork library 
'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

If i am using hardcode json object parameters its working fine but in case take value from EditText getting server error

## Error Trace

```
11-01 17:07:10.937 8456-8750/com.furdo.android E/Volley: [277] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://url/
11-01 17:07:10.938 8456-8456/com.furdo.android D/Volley: [1] override.onErrorResponse: Furdo:Proceed
11-01 17:07:10.938 8456-8456/com.furdo.android W/System.err: com.android.volley.ServerError
11-01 17:07:10.938 8456-8456/com.furdo.android W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:163)
11-01 17:07:10.938 8456-8456/com.furdo.android W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
11-01 17:07:11.549 8456-8536/com.furdo.android E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab6e9480
```

**jsonObject.put("mobile_no", str_email_or_phone); // getting value from editText not working
jsonObject.put("mobile_no", "9999999999"); // Hard code working**

Even String var="value" have same error

```
String str_email_or_phone = et_enter_no_or_email.getText().toString().trim();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("mobile_no", str_email_or_phone);// getting value from editText not working
        jsonObject.put("mobile_no", "9999999999");// Hard code working

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (jsonObject.length() >0) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Api.BASE_URL + Api.CHECK_USER, jsonObject,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {


            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                // hide the progress dialog
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Accept", "application/www.inception.v1");
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return params;
            }
        };
        // Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, "tag");
    }
```

Comment: Problem is obviously in the parameter. When debugging, what's the value of `str_email_or_phone` after initializing?

Comment: Getting proper value even when creating jsonObject.

Comment: It's a primite `String` var so it doesn't make sense that it somehow affects the request. Try to find differences between those requests, by debugging the client, logging in server, and you might even use Fiddler for monitoring requests but it's a bit overkill in my opinion.

Comment: Show the error trace?

Comment: Added error trace please check

Comment: Check your server. It is responding with a 400 (bad request). It doesn't like something in the field(s) of the request. Does it expect the field to be a number of a certain length? Include hyphens, dots, etc.?

Comment: Solved : server is giving response "400 bad request" ,its server side problem. Because if i am using wrong value they are giving response in 400 , so volley putting its in error.

Comment: No, it's not very likely to be Volley.  In fact, if you add `String var = "9999999999";  jsonObject.put("mobile_no", var);` it should work exactly the same as your line which is working. Check your server logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear from the stack trace that you are getting 400 response from your server. Your client (android code) is fine.

Check your server about why it responding fine for dummy requests but 400 for valid ones.